# How can I logout from Facebook in my custom Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, logout

I am building an Android application where I am using Facebook login, and after Facebook login, I get access_token and session that are stored in shared preferences in private mode.

I am using the Facebook login code below in an activity and I want the user to logout from Facebook from another fragment. How do I code on the fragment so that my current logged-in account logs out from Facebook?

Here is my Facebook login code:

```
/**
 * Function to login into facebook
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void loginToFacebook() {

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        // call getprofileinformation function to get user details
        getProfileInformation();

        Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[]{"email", "publish_stream"},
                new Facebook.DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();

                        // call getprofileinformation function to get user
                        // details
                        getProfileInformation();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For **4.x.x** version-

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private static void LogoutFB(Context context) {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) { 
        if (!session.isClosed()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            //clear your preferences if saved
        }
    } else { 
        session = new Session(context);
        Session.setActiveSession(session); 
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            //clear your preferences if saved 
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for Answering I try your answer but it look like it have some error showing could you please help me in solving that

Comment: I am using thus code exactly in my projects and there are no errors. What is that error  ?

Answer (score 0):

Call this [closeAndClearTokenInformation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/class/Session/#closeAndClearTokenInformation%28%29) method to logout from facbook.
This method closes the local in-memory Session object and clears any persisted token cache related to the Session.

Comment: This is used for 3.0 SDK but I right now I am using lower version

Comment: what version you are using?

Comment: i suggest, you should upgrade the library to latest version